# How to subtract buffers of identical ID in R (terra)?

Tags: r, buffer, terra

For a research project, I need to define treated and control areas around land parcels, located by coordinates and uniquely identified by an ID. The treated areas consist of disk-shaped buffers around coordinates, while the control areas are ring-shaped buffers surrounding each initial buffer.

[image: Inner circle is the treated area, while the external ring is the control area]

I use the "buffer" function in the terra package to define the disk-shaped buffers, from coordinates (sf_point) in a data frame (the inner circles in the previous image). I obtain a SpatVector object and add one attribute: the ID of each parcel.

My problem is to define the ring buffer surrounding each treated area. My first idea was to use the "buffer" function on the first disk-shaped buffer D1 to obtain a bigger disk D2, and then to use the "erase" function to obtain the ring R1 = erase(D2, D1).

This works perfectly when no buffer overlaps, as in the following picture.

[image: Here, no buffer overlap and the "erase" function works perfectly: we obtain a ring for each parcel.]

However, when two parcels are overlapping, the treated area of parcel A is also subtracted from the bigger disk of parcel B. In other words, the layer of treated areas is completely removed from the layer of bigger disks, and the output rings are cropped.

[image: The treated areas of both parcels are overlapping, and so do the "bigger disk"]

[image: When I subtract the treated areas to the bigger disks, rings of each parcel are cropped by the treated area of the other.]

This makes sense: `erase()` function just subtracts the two layers in arguments, regardless of the parcels.

To obtain two full, overlapping rings in the second case, I would need to be precise I want the subtraction to be performed parcel by parcel.

**Is there a way to do that in the terra package, or in R more generally?**

For the moment I have tried to group by ID with the tidyterra package, but it seems to work only for operations on the attribute, not the geometries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate position by position erasing the inner polygon:

```
library(terra)

set.seed(123)
sampling_area <- rast(crs='EPSG:32719')
pts <- spatSample(sampling_area, 20, as.points = TRUE)

d1 = buffer(pts, 40)
d2 = buffer(pts, 60)

result = sapply(1:20, function(X){erase(d2[X,],d1[X,])})

plot(vect(result))
```

[image]

Better than apply the function for all records at once:

```
plot(erase(d2,d1))
```

[image]